# JSF 2.0 keep checkboxes checked

Tags: java, jsf-2, checkbox

i have a jsf page which is sessionscoped and another requestscoped.  In my sessionscoped page, i have a set of checkboxes which upon user selection and form submission goes to the requestscoped page.

I simply want to keep the checkboxes checked in the sessionscoped page in the requestscoped page too.

Comment: When do you want to keep the checkboxes checked ?

Comment: @prajeeshkumar the checkboxes checked in the first page should be checked also in the second page

Comment: You can inject a session scoped bean into a request scoped bean, so when the request scoped page is loading, load the selections from session scoped bean. Also check EJP's solution

Comment: sounds like changing to view scope (from the request scope) , might help you...

Comment: @Daniel can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Have them get their values from the same bean property. I assume you will want to make the ones in the request-scoped page read-only?

Comment: yes they get their values from the same bean property.  But also i must be able to deselect and select checkboxes again in the request-scoped page.

Comment: @sameer If you want the request-scoped page to be able to affect the bean in the session scope, just don't make the request-scoped checkboxes readonly. Sounds like a nightmare to me ;-)

Comment: @ejb how would i know which checkbox was clicked and how to keep the same checkbox checked in the request-scoped page?

Comment: @sameer You don't have to know. The value is in the bean, it will be propagated to any checkbox that uses that property as a value. Have you *tried* any of this?

Comment: @EJB the value of the checkbox is undetermined as it comes from the database

Comment: @sameer How can data in a database be 'undetermined'? What database? First time you've mentioned it. The session-scoped page gets the initial value of the checkbox from the bean, and sets the value as modified by the user into the bean when the form is submitted. The request-scoped page then gets the value from the bean. So it is the same value. If there is more to this that you haven't told us, tell us.